# Jquery - selecting subset of data from ajax request not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using a modal to submit a form. I have it working correctly. The problem I am having with is replacing a subset of the modal with a subset of the data returned by the ajax request.

```
$.ajax({ url: actionUrl, method: 'post', data: dataToSend, processData: false, contentType: false })
  .done(function (data) {

   var newBody = $('.modal-body', data);
   console.log(newBody);
   placeholderElement.find('.modal-body').replaceWith(newBody);
   //other stuff
    }
```

I am trying to replace a subset of the modal that is active (i.e. get the modal-body) and replace it with a subset of the data from the ajax request.

My response from the ajax request in some cases will be below:

```
<div class="modal-body"><div class="alert alert-danger">Error</div></div>
```

But when my ajax request completes, the newbody is empty. The selector `($('.modal-body', data);`) returns an empty object. I'm not sure why as the selector it is looking for exists in the response and it should be returning the `<div class="alert alert-danger">Error</div>` as the new object.

If I modify my response as `<div class="modal"><div class="modal-body"><div class="alert alert-danger">Error</div></div></div>`, above selector then works.

My question is, why does one work vs the other not working?

**Works:** `$('.modal-body', '<div class="modal"><div class="modal-body"><div class="alert alert-danger">Error</div></div></div>');`

**Does Not Work**: `$('.modal-body', '<div class="modal-body"><div class="alert alert-danger">Error</div></div>');`

What do I need to do to simplify this? Any reason why one of the options does not work?

---

My `placeholderElement` at the point of the ajax request is a simple bootstrap modal:

```
<div class="modal fade"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="loading"></div>
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
//stuff
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark text-light" data-save="modal">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you consider using the error handle from Ajax? You could return false on server side. It's not a direct solution to your problem, but it could work. Check out this fiddle for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/Sk8erPeter/AGpP5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the jQuery function takes 2 arguments, one is a string (the selector) and the second have to be a DOM Element, Document, or jQuery element to be used as a context.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1

Finally, the reason because the second way doesnt works it's because the context takes the root node and ignore him to search the selector. This is a deduction I did >_<.

EDIT:

From the link i just give you:

"By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function."

So it's saying that it's ignoring the root element because says within ^^.

I hope i could help you :)

Comment: I believe you might be right. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

The selector `$('.modal-body', data)` tries to find an existing element with that class within data, but data must be an actual Element or another jQuery instance. If `data` is a string you can try to parse the HTML first:

```
var newBody = $('.modal-body', $(data));
```

Comment: I can't use a creation notation as I need to filter the response to find the content of the element with the .modal-body class. That was the whole reason why I ended up using the $('.modal-body',data) selector as it will filter the data and try and find the element with that class and get its inner html. I could write more js to go through the data separately to find that subset but was wondering why the selector does not work the way I'm thinking it does.

Comment: @Help123 Ohh right! I misunderstood. Going to update my answer.

Comment: I tried the updated answer with the same results unfortunately :(